Close pull request github action for Azure Static web apps
I used the following guide to setup the github action for a app deployed to azure static web apps. in the last piece of the workflow for closing a pull request
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - production
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - production

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "18"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build TypeScript
        run: npm run build

      # Merge new assets with existing assets in azure storage overwriting existing files
      - name: Upload assets to Azure Blob storage
        uses: azure/CLI@v2
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            az storage blob upload-batch --account-name ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} --account-key ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY }} --destination ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME }} --source dist --pattern "*" --destination-path "" --overwrite

      # Download all assets from Azure Blob storage
      - name: Download assets from Azure Blob storage
        uses: azure/CLI@v2
        with:
          inlineScript: |
            mkdir -p ${{github.workspace}}/new
            az storage blob download-batch --account-name ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} --account-key ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY }} --destination  ${{github.workspace}}/new --source ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME }}

      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_DESERT_043F33B0F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "${{github.workspace}}/new" 
          api_location: ""
          output_location: "dist"
          skip_app_build: true

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_DESERT_043F33B0F }}
          action: "close"



I'm getting error

Missing required input app_location

I'm not seeing anything about that mentioned in the provided guide and im not sure why would i need to give a app location for closing a pull request anyway
What is the correct action that needs to run when closing PR?
Note: to clarify the github action runs it just when i open it in my editor i get an error saying that its missing
EDIT: screenshot of error


Please add app_location: "<path_to_your_app>" to the YML file. Could you please tell me which application you are deploying to the static web? Have you made any changes in the web app?

@Sampath im deploying a react app and the workflow looks pretty much exactly as the guide i linked above. Why should i add the app_location to closing pull request, its not on the guide?

It determines the location of application

Any resources you can point me to for this? My understanding was that all the close pull request workflow does is close the preview env, and if so there shouldnt be a need to give app_location, but it seems like im wrong

The recommended location for the  staticwebapp.config.json  is in the folder set as the  app_location  in the  workflow file. However, you can place the file in any subfolder within the folder set as the  app_location. Additionally, if there's a build step, you must ensure that the build step outputs the file to the root of the output_location.See the  example configuration  file for details.

The error you are facing is due to not providing app_location: "<path_to_your_app>" in the YML file.

Refer this MSDoc for a list of available configuration settings in the workflow file. See the example configuration file for details.

I have deployed a sample React app to a static web.

Configured Azure Static Web Apps according to the link and added staticwebapp.config.json in the root folder.


staticwebapp.config.json
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html"
  }
}


Below is my YML file for a static web app;
Replace app_location as per your  folder  structure.
As my yml file is in root directory, so i have set app_loaction  as  app_location: "/".

My YML File :
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_PROUD_SKY_0046A9D0F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
        
        
          app_location: "/"
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "build" 
         

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_PROUD_SKY_0046A9D0F }}
          action: "close"


Deployment status:



Your workflow has the same error/warning :-) in the close pull request job you do not provide the app_location. thats atleast the warning im getting.

you check my git once.Replace app_location as per your folder structure.

on the last with in the close pull request is where im getting the error. ill post a screenshot of it

i updated my question with screenshot

if possible can you share your git?

i updated the question to include the full workflow file.

checking from my end.
